# How do I install XDebug on docker's official php (debian based) image?

Tags: php, docker

Exactly as [How do I install XDebug on docker's official php-fpm-alpine image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46825502/how-do-i-install-xdebug-on-dockers-official-php-fpm-alpine-image) but instead of the alpine image I'm looking for the debian based image (`php:7.1-fpm-stretch`).

Essentially, how should I install XDebug? Through Debian's packages? pecl? Or some alternative?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [official image documentation](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/php/README.md#pecl-extensions) indicates that you can use `pecl` to install xdebug. Since xdebug is not available through other channels, this is the preferred method.

> Some extensions are not provided with the PHP source, but are instead available through PECL. To install a PECL extension, use pecl install to download and compile it, then use docker-php-ext-enable to enable it:

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm-stretch
RUN pecl install xdebug-2.6.0 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
```

---

For <= PHP 5.6.?:

```
RUN pecl install xdebug-2.5.5 \
  && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to installing it I had to do the following in order to get it working:

/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini

```
zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/xdebug.log"
```

And also set a environment variable in my docker config for the container:

```
  - PHP_IDE_CONFIG=serverName=exampleAbc
```