# xdebug extenstion does not install with php:5.6-apache

Tags: php, docker-compose, dockerfile, xdebug

i am trying to install xdebug into my dockerfile build but it does not install with  php:5.6-apache as the base image.

it returns the following message;

```
ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y   ...  
&& pecl install xdebug   returned a non-zero code: 1
```

this is my dockerfile:

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

ENV S6_OVERLAY_VERSION 1.11.0.1


RUN tar xzf /tmp/s6-overlay-amd64.tar.gz -C /

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libldap2-dev \
    --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && docker-php-ext-configure ldap --with-libdir=lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install ldap \
     && pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql

RUN a2enmod rewrite

COPY ./docker/rootfs /
COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["/init"]
```

How can I install xedbug with PHP5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dockerfile

```
RUN git clone https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug.git \
&& cd xdebug \
&& git checkout tags/XDEBUG_2_5_5 \
&& phpize \
&& ./configure --enable-xdebug \
&& make \
&& make install
```

Whether you need the below or not depends on your exact usage. But I'll include it anyway so you can try things out.

.bashrc

```
export PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=docker";
```

php.ini - where the ip should be your local machine for your docker network. The log is there just to help you debug if the install doesn't work.

```
xdebug.remote_host=172.20.0.1
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
xdebug.remote_log=/srv/www/var/log/xdebug.log
```

Comment: hi George. thanks for help but it did not work, returned following error; Check for supported PHP versions... configure: error: not supported. Need a PHP version >= 7.0.0 and < 7.3.0 (found 5.6.40)

Comment: Ah sorry, try a different tag version. I'll edit the question from 2.6.1 to 2.5.5 as I believe that is the latest version supporting php 5.6

Comment: hi again. it still shows an error: error: pathspec 'tags/2.5.5' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Comment: Sorry looks like they changed the format of their tags recently, here's a new one

Comment: THANKS MATE. IT WORKED

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer assumes `git` is installed in your container. I think this is the "more correct" way to install a specific version of xdebug:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache $PHPIZE_DEPS \
    && pecl install xdebug-2.5.5 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
```

cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46831699/2105015